# Starting a python script on boot (startx) with an absolute path, in which there are relative paths

Tags: python, path, absolute-path

I realise this question may already exist, but the answers I've found haven't worked and I have a slightly different setup.

I have a python file `/home/pi/python_games/frontend.py` that I am trying to start when lxde loads by placing `@python /home/pi/python_games/frontend.py` in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`.

It doesn't run and there are no error messages.

When trying to run `python /home/pi/python_games/frontend.py`, python complains about not being able to find the files that are loaded using relative links eg: `/home/pi/python_games/image.png` is called with `image.png`. Obviously one solution would be to give these resources absolute paths, but the python program also calls other python programs in its directory that also have relative paths, and I don't want to go changing all them.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change your current working directory inside the script before you start calling your relative imports, use os.chdir("absolute path on where your script lives").

Comment: hey thanks. The script is left running in the background with &. Will your solution affect the scripts that are started after this one?

Comment: no, it will change the working directory of the script where you added the command only.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change your current working directory, in your`frontend.py`script you could use the value of the predefined`__file__`module attribute, which will be the absolute pathname of the script file, to determine absolute paths to the other files in the same directory.

Functions in the`os.path`module, such as`split()`and`join()`, will make doing this fairly easy.